# Set vm.max_map_count on cluster nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I try to install ElasticSearch (latest) on a cluster nodes on Google Container Engine but ElasticSearch needs the variable : `vm.max_map_count` to be >= 262144.

If I ssh to every nodes and I manually run :

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

All goes fine then, but any new node will not have the specified configuration.

So my questions is :

Is there a way to load a system configuration on every nodes at boot time ?
Deamon Set would not be the good solution because inside a docker container, the system variables are read-only.

I'm using a fresh created cluster with the `gci` node image.

Comment: Why doesn't a DaemonSet work? You can run the pod in privileged mode to have root-equivalent permissions on each host.

Comment: Yes I thought if this solution recently and I'm gonna test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use a DaemonSet to emulate the behavior of a startup script. If the script needs to do root-level actions on the node, you can configure the DaemonSet pods to run in privileged mode.

For an example of how to do this, see https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/startup-script

Comment: I finally updated the elasticsearch image to run the command :
`sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`
And I run this container in privileged mode. It's not the safest option but it works.
I think that the better solution is yours because it prevent from running the elasticsearch container in privileged mode.

Answer (score 13):

I found another solution while looking at [this repository](https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster/blob/master/es-client.yaml).

It relies on the use of [an init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/abstractions/init-containers/), the plus side is that only the init container is running with privileges:

```
annotations:
    pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[
      {
      "name": "sysctl",
        "image": "busybox",
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
        "command": ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"],
        "securityContext": {
          "privileged": true
        }
      }
    ]'
```

There is a new syntax available since Kubernetes 1.6 which still works for 1.7. Starting with 1.8 this new syntax is required. The declaration of init containers is moved to `spec`:

```
  - name: init-sysctl
    image: busybox
    command:
    - sysctl
    - -w
    - vm.max_map_count=262144
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

Answer (score 3):

As Robert pointed out, a DaemonSet could run as a startup script. Unfortunately, GKE will only let you run a DaemonSet with restartPolicy set as Always.

So in order to prevent k8s to continually restart the container after running `sysctl`, it has to sleep after the setup and preferably just run on selected nodes. It isn't an elegant solution, but it's elastic at least.

**Example**:

`es-host-setup` Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
CMD sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144; sleep 365d
```

DaemonSet resource file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: es-host-setup
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: es-host-setup
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: es-host-setup
        image: es-host-setup
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      nodeSelector:
        pool: elasticsearch
```

Comment: This what I've done: set the vm-max then sleep a very long time:

`command: [ "sh", "-c", "sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144 && sleep 2147483647" ]`

Comment: On Kubernetes 1.6 or newer you can use initContainers as on helm's elasticsearch chart:  https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/incubator/elasticsearch/templates/client-deployment.yaml#L44

Answer (score 0):

Found the Essy solution for this
Check the opensearch pod Scheduled nodes, Provide a label to node
Deploy below the pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: os-pod
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: os-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd # node label
  initContainers:
  - name: init-sysctl
    image: busybox
    command:
    - sysctl
    - -w
    - vm.max_map_count=262144
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```